# How to redirect based on URL

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins

I am using **Wp Store Locator** plugin.And I have Modified it according my need.But I am stuck in redirection.

Basically this plugin works with short code.So at the time of listing my URL is like that : `localhost/wordpress/?page_id=391`

Now there is one link which is redirects me to `http://localhost/wordpress/?wpsl_id=3`

Here is code for that :

```
    add_action("template_redirect", 'my_theme_redirect');

    function my_theme_redirect() {

            $dpath = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ;
        $templatefilename = 'single-store.php';
        if (strpos($dpath,'wpsl_id') !== false){    
                $return_template = get_template_directory() .'/' .$templatefilename  ;
                //$nurl = get_permalink($return_template);
                //echo $return_template; exit;
                wp_redirect($return_template);

                exit;               
            }
    }
```

This code is not redirecting me to any-where.It stays on the same page **localhost/wordpress/?page_id=391** What might be the issue?

Anyone can suggest me how can I direct to URL when it detects `wpsl_id` in the URL ? I want to redirect them to plugin's template folder where I have added a file for that.

**EDITED** :

I have added above code in the plugin file just above the short code. Hope I has nothing to do with this issue :)

Comment: Your `wp_redirect()` function is redirecting to a page template, not a valid site URL...

Comment: You have to use `template_include` filter hook instead of `template_redirect`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Comment: @rnevius sorry I did not get you.What am I missing ? Or Where am I making mistake ?

Comment: @jogesh_pi Your suggestion is not working .. In fact it is not showing anything. Only blank page.

Answer (score -2):

The template name looks fine. You just need to register the template before you call it.

Add this filter so this will execute before your action:

add_filter( 'template_include', 'single-store' );

Comment: You are looking very new to the Wordpress.Please give helpful answers or search well before answer otherwise you will have downvotes.

Comment: Dude second parameter has to be a function, not a page name.Thanks for your time.I got solution,

Comment: Once you add the template using the template_include hook then you can call your template properly is what people tried to tell you.